# Why am I getting an out of memory error?

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I keep getting this error?

```
07-25 17:04:00.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(420): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
07-25 17:04:00.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(420):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.init(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:79)
07-25 17:04:00.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(420):     at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.createSessionInputBuffer(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:83)
```

Everytime I try to run a this method:

```
public void getImages() throws IOException{


    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("https://sites.google.com/site/theitrangers/images/webImages.txt");
    HttpResponse response;

        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


            HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

            BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);

            InputStream is = buf.getContent();


            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line + "\n");

              imageUrl = total.toString();
              Log.v("getImage1", "Retreived image");
            }
     }
```

All this method is doing is retreiving URL from a text file hosted on a website.

EDIT: LINE OF CODE WHERE DEBUG IS POINTING ME TO. WHEN IT RUNS I GET OUT OF MEMORY ERROR.

```
 public void getImages() throws IOException{


    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("https://sites.google.com/site/theitrangers/images/webImages.txt");
    HttpResponse response;

**Specifically here:**  response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: Please search for similar problems. I am sure you will get quite a few similar threads where people have already discussed this issue.

Comment: Could you post the complete stack trace? Tough to nail down the exact problematic line in your code. Definitely a memory leak though.

Comment: @Sagar Hatekar Posted where the debug is pointing to above in the edit.

Comment: `VM` doesnt hold anything against you. You are getting an OOM because your program must have ran out of memory. :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're possibly getting the OOM `cos you're loading that text file, that should be large, in memory on that StringBuilder. You should write this file to a local file instead of the StringBuilder to avoid the error.

Comment: okay so maybe i could have the code that fetches the string from the text doc. Stored inside of a SQLite database and have it pull from there. The only problem is i will be changing the url's often. And i dont want to keep storing urls in a database having it grow in size for old URLs.

Comment: You can just clean the database on every import.

Comment: The content of the referenced file is simply: `https://sites.google.com/site/theitrangers/images/ncaa12.jpg `.  Certainly not large enough for an OOM, not even on my wristwatch.

Comment: Well you... Its just a simple text URL. So what do you guys think it could be? When i run it on my real life debug device it runs great

Comment: Check the memory limit for the VM you're using, maybe it's too low.

Comment: I ran it on my device and so everytime the i swipe to view the different images fetched, when image is off the screen in swipped back on it fetched the images all over again. using wayyyy to much cpu. causing a ANR.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Droi Fu library?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no leak in your application, then this is probably the same issue as discussed (and fixed!) in [Android HttpClient OOM on 4G/LTE (HTC Thunderbolt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358014/android-httpclient-oom-on-4g-lte-htc-thunderbolt)